# sound a BEEP through cgwin bash Linux terminal that connected to though the new Windows 11 Terminal app

Tags: linux, terminal, cygwin

is there a way to found a BEEP through Linux terminal that connected to though the new Windows 11 Terminal app?

I already tried most things like the beep, echo 007 etc.
but none sound through the linux terminal (using cygwin / bash.exe) and onto the Windows Terminal.

thanks

Sean

Comment: Have you tried `echo '^V^G'` at bash prompt where ^V is ctrl-v and ^G is ctrl-g. Or `echo ^G` at cmd in terminal?

Comment: ya naaa did not work

Comment: be sure to set the Bell on the Mintty Terminal option

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Turn on terminal sounds in Cygwin mintty terminal, and send the bell character to the terminal with:
   `echo -ne '\a'; echo -ne "\007"; printf '\a'`
2. send a sound file directly to the `/dev/dsp`, like this:
   `cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/Media/ding.wav > /dev/dsp`